# ETW ProcessTrace() trying to reserve 1GB of memory on XP?

Tags: memory-management, out-of-memory, etw

I'm currently writing an application that uses the NT Kernel Logger via the ETW trace functions. It consumes in real-time mode. It works fine on my Windows 7 test machine but on my XP VM I was getting regular out of memory exceptions.

Using APIMonitor (amazing tool btw) I tracked it down to a call to NtAllocateVirtualMemory() with the ProcessTrace() Win32 API call itself. It is trying to allocate 1GB of contiguous memory, as can be seen in the screenshot.

[image: api-monitor]

Has anyone encountered this before? I cannot conceive why it would need to allocate so much memory. Additionally, with the call occurring deep within the ProcessTrace() call stack in an undocumented Win32 API function (WmiMofEnumerateResourcesA()), it seems like I'm not really going to be able to influence it. Has anyone encountered this before? I'd appreciate any potential solutions.

I need to support XP/2003 and on 32-bit versions I really can't assume that 1GB of contiguous memory will be available. Real-time processing is also a requirement. However, any workarounds using file-backed logging that doesn't involve losing events I could consider e.g. so i'd "real-time" process new events added to the .ETL files instead, if that is possible.

Comment: Yes I have seen this, it went away with windows updates!

Comment: Do you have an idea of which update fix this issue?

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed with SP3